# Printing specific tables/rows in Razor View

Tags: javascript, html, razor, printing

This seems like a trivial question, but I need to print blocks of "< tr >< /tr >" that are within a table. The following is my Razor view which loops through the data and everything looks nice but the individual sections are not printable. Is there any way to make the individual sections printable?

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-responsive table-striped">
    @{ var previousheader = ""; }

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.TrmnlGrp_Description_TEMP != "" && item.TrmnlGrp_Description_TEMP != previousheader)
        {
            previousheader = item.TrmnlGrp_Description_TEMP;

            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" style="padding:5px; background:#808080">
                    <b>@Html.DisplayName(item.TrmnlGrp_Description_TEMP)</b>
                </td>
                <td style="padding:5px; background:#808080">
                    <input type="button" name="print" value="Print" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Vendor
                </th>
                <th>
                    Terminal
                </th>
                <th>
                    Eff. Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Diesel
                </th>
                <th>
                    Regular
                </th>
                <th>
                    Mid
                </th>
                <th>
                    Premium
                </th>
            </tr>
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Vend_Description_TEMP)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Trmnl_Description_TEMP)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Fuelcost_EFF_DateTime_TEMP)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Diesel)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Regular_Unleaded)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Midgrade_Gasoline)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Premium_Unleaded_Gas)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

Comment: What do you mean by printable? You mean you want to pick 2 rows and print it on paper?

Comment: Either way what I would do if I were you is to allow a client side filter for the data in the table and only show data you want to print.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. How would one add a client side filter?

Comment: Allow the user to choose from some filter criteria, pass the filter criteria to the controller, filter the data and return it, then clear the table and rebuild it with the requested data.

Comment: If you're using EF use something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application